# What am I doing wrong with isalnum() in c?

Tags: c, string

The code is supposed to allow the user to write a phrase, count how many characters are there and tell if it's alphanumeric or not, however even when I use '+' or sorta the counter for alphanumeric characters rises too. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXR 100
#define MAXC 10     
#define TERMINATOR "END"

int main() {

    char phrase[MAXR];
    char text[MAXC][MAXR];
  
    int i;
    int countalnum = 0;
    int countchar = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXC; i++) {
  
        fgets(phrase, MAXR, stdin);
        phrase[strlen(phrase) - 1] = '\0';
    
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(phrase); j++) {
            countchar++;
            if (isalnum(phrase[i]) == 0)
                countalnum++;
        }
    
        if (strcmp(phrase, TERMINATOR) == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }
    
        strcpy(text[i], phrase);
    }
    ...
}
```

if I wasn't clear enough, feel free to tell me so I can try to explain it better to you

Comment: `isalnum()` returns 0 for any characters that **isn't** neither alpha neither numeric. Simply reverse the condition

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalnum

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong because we don't know what you want to do. Neither of the `countchar` or `countalnum` variables are ever *used* in the code you've shown.

Comment: @Cid tried it and it didn't work either, they both kept rising

Comment: @xing oh jeez thanks, that must be it. Yup, just tried it, it was that dumb, thank you

Comment: Don't use `strlen` in the condition for the loop.  Computing string length is expensive, and should not be done for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Both @Cid and @xing comments are correct.
you need to change the `isalnum()` condition and you used `i` where it should have been `j`.

Next time just add some debug prints and see the flow, you will very quickly figure where you have gone wrong.

Here is a fixed version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXR 100
#define MAXC 10     
#define TERMINATOR "END"

int main()
{
    char phrase[MAXR];
    char text[MAXC][MAXR];
  
    int i;
    int countalnum = 0;
    int countchar = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXC; i++) {
  
        if (!fgets(phrase, MAXR, stdin))
            break;

        int len = strlen(phrase); // better to cache this value
        // strip the trailing newline if any
        if (len > 0 && phrase[len - 1] == '\n')
            phrase[--len] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(phrase, TERMINATOR) == 0) {
            break;
        }   
    
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            countchar++;
            if (isalnum((unsigned char)phrase[j]))
                countalnum++;
        }
    
        strcpy(text[i], phrase);
    }

    // The result doesn't include the terminator "END"
    printf("Total chars: %d\n", countchar);
    printf("Total alphanumeric chars: %d\n", countalnum);
    return 0;
}
```